# Does case class' copy-method use Structural Sharing?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, copy, clone, immutability

Structural Sharing in Scala Immutable Collections is quite straightforward and there's a lot of material floating around to understand it.

Now every Scala `case class` automatically defines a `copy` method, which returns a new copy with the new attributes specified, my question is, does the method use Structural Sharing?

So when I have a

```
case class A(x: HugeObject, y: Int)
```

and call the `copy` method

```
val a = A(x,y)
val b = a.copy(y = 5)
```

Does it copy x?

Comment: I actually don't think "structural sharing" is a relevant concept here. It's simply a shallow copy rather than a deep copy. The entire top level of the structure is copied, the copying just don't go any deeper than that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A case class is flat tuple, as such when using `copy` a new instance is allocated with slots for each product element. However, the elements themselves are not in any form duplicated but shared by reference (except for the value passed into the `copy` method).

```
case class Foo(a: AnyRef, b: AnyRef)

val f1 = Foo(new AnyRef, new AnyRef)
val f2 = f1.copy(a = new AnyRef)
f1.a == f2.a // false
f1.b == f2.b // true
f1.b eq f2.b // true
```

So in your case, `x` is only reused as the same reference but not structurally duplicated.

Comment: Just tried it in the Repl and it's exactly right. Such an awesome feature for Swift to have.

Comment: @LukaJacobowitz what do you mean by awesome feature? The sane thing to do is _not_ making a deep copy. If you adhere to immutable structures that is the right and efficient way to work. If you put mutable objects into a case class, you are doing it _wrong_.

Comment: It is the sane thing to do and I think it's great Scala is so consistent. With `copy` working with immutable values is just as easy as with mutable values.

Comment: I was confused because you made a comment about Swift, so assumed Swift will copy the deep tree.

Comment: Wow, I'm sorry, I should get back to work. Of course meant Scala :D