# Case class .copy() and large objects

Tags: scala

Let's assume large objects (multi-megabyte attachments in my case, several thousands per day) are received via a REST endpoint and stored in a case class like this:

```
case class Box(largeBase64Object: String, results: List[String])
```

Now, instances of this case class are processed in multiple, consecutive steps (chain). Each chain step may change the instance by calling `box.copy(results = "foo" :: box.results)` (actually, this example is simplified, it is actually a shapeless HList which stores the result of each step).

Single steps might be, e.g. virus scanning, which would add the scanner's result (infected/not infected as a `Boolean`) to the `results` list.

This approach, however, would always create a new copy of the potentially large attachments. Yes, garbage collection would collect the outdated copy sooner or later, but I'm still afraid of the potential overhead as we are talking of about several gigabytes per day of attachment data.

The other obvious approach would be to store the attachment in a global mutable `Map` and to just store a reference in the `Box`. This would avoid copying the attachments once per step but the nice properties of completely immutable data structures would be gone.

What is the canonical way to handle these situation? Has anyone pointers to benchmarks reflecting this scenario (copy vs global storage)?

Comment: It won't create copies of attachments. All copies will reference the same `largeBase64Object` value.

Comment: Oh really? That's cool...could you pls. add this as an answer, so that I could accept it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does case class' copy-method use Structural Sharing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35718363/does-case-class-copy-method-use-structural-sharing)

Comment: Jep, duplicate!

Comment: I actually don't think "structural sharing" is a relevant concept here. It's simply a shallow copy rather than a deep copy.

Comment: Yes, but in the referenced answer it is pointed out that copy by reference is used (for non-modified fields).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Objects referenced by the case class are not copied, only the case class itself, all references will be to the same objects as the original (except for those that you explicitly change of course).

We can't look at the source code for the copy method bbecause it is generated by the compiler, but we can use the `-Xprint:typer` compiler flag to see what code it generates.

For you case class

```
case class Box(largeBase64Object: String, results: List[String])
```

We see the generated method (I am using scalac 2.12.3)

```
<synthetic> def copy(largeBase64Object: String = largeBase64Object, results: List[String] = results): Box = new Box(largeBase64Object, results);
<synthetic> def copy$default$1: String = Box.this.largeBase64Obj
<synthetic> def copy$default$2: List[String] = Box.this.results;
```

As we can see, the copy method simply creates a new instance of the case class, using the objects it gets passed, and will default to just using the fields of the case class directly without any sort of copying.